# How to insert a 3rd column value based on 2nd column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to insert a value into table with 2nd column value output

i want to insert a 3 column value based on 2 column value output

Query

```
insert into table1 (id, type, desc)
values
select id#,
case 
when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'I' then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'abc')
when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'L' and LEN(NUMBER) > 0 then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'def')   
end,
case
when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'M' and type  = 1 then 'dwcerf'
when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'O' and type = 2 then 'scef'
End
from table2
```

type = 1 and type = 2 is output of 2nd column

How to do this, Please suggest

Comment: Please show the current result and expected result as text

Comment: Over 3,700 points at the time you posted this and still not enough information. You have been around here long enough to know that without details nobody can really help. Post a proper question and you will get a proper answer.

Comment: Even worse...you posted this question once today already and it got closed as being a duplicate. Sad...

Comment: Any of the suggested answers did help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query:

```
insert into table1 (id, type, desc)
SELECT  *,
        case
            when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'M' and type  = 1 then 'dwcerf'
            when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'O' and type = 2 then 'scef'
            End
FROM (
    select id#,
    case 
    when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'I' then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'abc')
    when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'L' and LEN(NUMBER) > 0 then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'def')   
    end as [type]
    from table2
    ) as p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert with 2nd column value and then update of the 3rd column value with select from previous. I don't know context of your insert, but don't you have this information available somewhere where you are running this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you need intermediate vars to take part in futher calculations, use APPLY.

```
insert into table1 (id, type, desc)
select id#,
  ca.var,
  case
    when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'M' and ca.var = 1 then 'dwcerf'
    when CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'O' and ca.var = 2 then 'scef'
  End
from table2
cross apply (
   select var = case 
          when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'I' then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'abc')
          when CUSTOMER_CODE = 'L' and LEN(NUMBER) > 0 then (select type# from customertype where typecode = 'def')   
      end) ca
```

Hope `typecode` is unique in `customertype`, or you'll get an error.